# absolute positioning relative to body of a div generated dynamically 

Tags: css, position

can i place a div at absolute position relative to body which is dynamically generated inside a a div which position is relative

here is my scenario i have to keep it this way only

http://jsfiddle.net/bipin000/swqqH/

Comment: question is not clear please give some more details.

Comment: @ZaheerAhmed i have linked it to jsfiddle please have a look

Comment: its not clear too what you want?

Comment: @ZaheerAhmed my element should be generated inside the form and div containing div but it should view like the top div

Answer (score 3, accepted):

okay its not possible until you make parent div `position:static` and then make dynamic div `position:absolute`

http://jsfiddle.net/swqqH/25/

Comment: It's still positioned relative to the parent, not relative to the body.

Answer (score 1):

No, that's not possible. As the parent div is positioned, it becomes the offset parent, so the absolutely positioned div will be placed relative to the outer div, not relative to the body.